# Como escribir la ruta correcta en el cmd para compilar mi código en less?

Tags: css, less

Hola estoy estudiando un curso en línea css y estoy viendo el tema de Less acabo de descargar esta versión lessc 4.1.3y tengo que compilar el codigo de sass para eso el instructor escribe esta línea de código en cmd como se ve en el cuadro rojo

[image: cmd]

Yo escribí la misma línea de código del instructor en el cmd y el nombre de mi carpeta es MASTER CSS .Pero me sale error. y eso que tengo instalado el less.

[image: img2]

Me pueden ayudar por favor?. Necesito compilar el less en cmd. Que tengo que hacer para que compile? gracias

Answer (score 0):

> yo escribí la misma línea de código del instructor en el cmd

No, no es la misma línea, tu escribes **MASTER CSS** mientras que en el curso es **master-css**

Te recomiendo lo siguiente:

- Usa nombres en minúscula
- Usa nombres unidos ya sea en CamelCase, o camelCase o unidos-por-guiones
- Prueba poniendo el nombre de tu carpeta tal cual la tienes ahora (separada) entre comillas, así: `"MASTER CSS"`.
- Por ultimo, cuando uses el comando **cd**, escribe las primeras 3 letras del nombre de la carpeta a la que quieres ingresar y presiona TAB. Esto complementara tu búsqueda y por ejemplo si tienes dos o mas carpetas que inicien con la misma palabra (master por ejemplo) presiona varias veces TAB, hasta que te muestre la que tu quieres.